# Completar dos arreglos con la misma cantidad de elementos

Tags: javascript, array

Tengo dos arreglos los cuales necesito que los dos queden del mismo tamaño, para dejarlos del mismo tamaño se deben de llenar con ceros `0`

```
const datos= [[1,3,5,8,7],
              [9,3]
             ];
```

El resultado esperado es:

```
const datos= [[1,3,5,8,7],
              [9,3,0,0,0]
             ];
```

Posdata: Los arreglos pueden ser n, no necesariamente 2 arreglos, esto es lo que he intentado:

```
  const max = Math.max(...datos.map(dato => dato.length));
  for (let dato of datos) {
    while (dato.length < max) {
      dato.push(0);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Y que intentaste hasta ahora? donde esta el error?

Comment: Bienvenidx a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo: "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato de preguntas y respuestas del sitio. 
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: @Alfabravo mil disculpas, por no adjuntar el codigo, estaba disvaiando muchisimo y no tenia idea como abordar el problema de una forma optima, por lo general trate de aportar algo de codigo, pero eran muchos ciclos innecesarios, pero igualmente lo tendre en cuenta.

Comment: @Manuco Bianco no tenia ni idea como lograr atacer el problema y que el resultado no fuera una suma de ciclos innecesarios, pero creo que lo pude saca, espero sea algo optimo

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero que hice es averiguar el array con mayor longitud para ello use un map para obtener todos los valores.

Después utilicé Math.max para averiguar el máximo valor del array.

Seguidamente hice un map del array original para convertir el array original en el array deseado, cada elemento lo concadenaba para llegar a la longitud deseada rellenado de su valor original y de ceros.

```js
const exampleArray = [[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3],[1,2]]

const maxLength = Math.max(...exampleArray.map(elem => elem.length))

const result = exampleArray.map(arr => [].concat(arr, Array(maxLength - arr.length).fill(0) ))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Me voy a poner en el peor de los casos en los que no sabes cuantos números son en total.

Primero tendrías que recorrer el array buscando el mayor número de números.

```
var max=0;
for(i=0;i<datos.length;i++){
    if(max<=datos[i].length){
        max=datos[i].length;
    }
}
```

De esa forma obtendrás el número máximo de números que tienen que tener. Ahora tendrás que añadir tantos 0 como falten en cada array

```
for(i=0;i<datos.length;i++){
    for(j=0;j<max;j++){
        if(datos[i][j]==null){
            datos[i][j]=0;
        }
    }
}
```